# Magento: Prevent products without images from showing

Tags: magento

We've just done a mass import. We have allot of products showing up without images and we need to prevent that. There not supposed to have images or show but we can't set them to "Not visible anywhere" in the CSV.

So if images = 0 don't show anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the category collection so that it only loads Products that have images. If you use flat tables (recommended), it should not be very difficult to add a filter method to the collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection.

A more dirty but easier way would be to just not display the products without images in the product listing template (app/design/frontend/templates/catalog/product/list.phtml). The image helper is used there to display the product images. Whenever the default image is about to be shown, you could continue to the next product. But remember, that the products without images are loaded anyway, which is really dirty.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into the first option so as to stay clean :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting "Not Visible Individually" in the "Visibility" column of your CSV whenever the "image" column is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We can't do this because we'll have some configurable products coming over in the CSV that should be visible and some that shouldn't. The ones that should be visible, have an image, so that's the thread I was trying to focus on.

Comment: I didn't mean do it for all products, only the ones that need hiding.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that we're exporting from another system over 20,000 products. So we can't select only some to not be visible. I was wondering if there was anything we could from an sql level?